# How do I select (N-1) rows from my MYSQL table where N is the number of rows fetched, while I am fetching DISTINCT elements?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mysql query where I am trying to fetch `DISTINCT` elements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`Prev Date`), `Current Date` 
FROM `electric_transaction` 
WHERE `Flag`=1 
    AND `ipas_flag`=1 
    AND `SlNo` != (
                SELECT MAX(`SlNo`) FROM `electric_transaction`
    );
```

I want to fetch all the rows except the last one.

How do I proceed? Please guide me.

Comment: Which is the last one? You don't even have an order

Comment: I tried to fetch by excluding the `max(SlNo)` which is my primary key, but the last row  still shows

Comment: `distinct` is a **modifier** added to `select` e.g. `select distinct prev_date, current_date`. `distinct` is **NOT** a function, so parentheses around column name/s have NO effect, and it will consider all columns to determine which **rows** are duplicated or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an offset of 1 record in your `LIMIT` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Prev Date`,`Current Date` 
FROM `electric_transaction` 
WHERE `Flag` = 1 
AND `ipas_flag` = 1
ORDER BY SlNo DESC
LIMIT 1, 1000000
```

Comment: Nothing shows, when I run this query

Comment: Sorry, you have to switch the numbers in LIMIT. Changed my answer. You can try again